# How do I tell Visual Studio to Push Updated ".asp" Files to the Output Directory When Debugging/Tell IIS Express not to Cache Them

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, iis, iis-express

I have a project which is part ASP.net and part Classic ASP.  Sometimes while while running the debugger (using IIS-Express) I will make a change to the classic code, save it and refresh the page (I have Chrome's "Disable cache" feature enabled) but the changes will not be reflected in the page.  Sometimes the changes will appear after a few minutes or a few refreshes.  However if I make a change to a css or js file the change will appear on the first refresh.

I thought IIS Express might be caching the file it's self as the document is parsed by the web server before being handed to the client so I added this to my Web.config (based on answers to this question [How do I stop IIS from caching any files, ever, under any circumstances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29934588/how-do-i-stop-iis-from-caching-any-files-ever-under-any-circumstances)) -

```
  <caching enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

and added my Web.Debug.config like this -

```
<system.webServer>
  <caching enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

and added this to my Web.Release.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <caching enabled="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

but still no better.

Comment: I asked about this at [IIS Express overly caching classic ASP pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673523/iis-express-overly-caching-classic-asp-pages) but haven't found a suitable answer yet.